# How to prevent admin user to access cache management from magento admin panel?

Tags: magento

I want to disable cache management from backend. Admin will not be able to enable/disable or flush cache. It should not cause any issue at frontend as well as backend.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found small fixes to disable cache management.

Put given code in config.xml of new or existing module.

**Package/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<adminhtml>
   <menu>
      <system>
         <children>
            <cache>
               <disabled>1</disabled>
            </cache>
         </children>
      </system>
   </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating roles for admin... one is super admin and another is sub admin..
in sub admin you can restrict admin users..